# How to adjust indentation of bullets using HTML (Unordered List) in R Shiny environment?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, modal-dialog

I'm trying to adjust the alignment of bullets using HTML for text rendered in R Shiny modal dialogue, as shown in the image below. I've gone through sources like W3 Schools and haven't found a solution yet. The example code, somewhat representative of my larger App, is posted at the bottom. Are there any solutions for this sort of bullet alignment?

[image]

Example code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(uiOutput("header")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$header <- renderUI({
    fluidPage(
        paste("Testing modal:"),
        tags$button(
          id = "show", class = "btn action-button",
          tags$img(src = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png")
        )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      tags$div(style="text-align:justify",
      HTML("
      <p>Studying the pig:</p>
      <ul>
      <li>Pigs eat anything</li>
      <li>Pigs are fat</li>
      </ul>
      "))
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's the best way:

```html
      <p>Studying the pig:</p>
      <ul>
      <li style='margin-left: -25px;'>Pigs eat anything</li>
      <li style='margin-left: -25px;'>Pigs are fat</li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Perfect, works great! I learned a new trick, embedding formatting commands inside the < > brackets.

Comment: @Village.Idyot I left another approach below.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the indentation is controlled by setting the `padding-left` property of the ul-tag (it isn't necessary to modify each li-tag):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(uiOutput("header")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$header <- renderUI({
    fluidPage(
      paste("Testing modal:"),
      tags$button(
        id = "show",
        class = "btn action-button",
        tags$img(src = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png")
      )
    )
  })
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      tags$div(style = "text-align: justify;",
               tags$p("Studying the pig:"),
               tags$ul(style = "padding-left: 15px;",
                       lapply(list("Pigs eat anything", "Pigs are fat"), tags$li)
                       )
      )
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```